# Watching for scale/zoom changes in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: scale, feature-layer, zoom, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, event-listener

I am trying to add an event listener for when the scale of the map changes, that is scale or zoom level changes in order to enable or disable feature layer label text. When the user zooms in to a larger scale I want the labels to be visible and when the scale is lowered the labels should go away. After defining the MapView I tried the following

```
 view.on("zoom", function(){alert();});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The practice in version 3.x of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript of using event listeners has been superseded in 4.x by a new paradigm: *watchable* properties.

from the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/migrating/index.html#properties):

> Prior to 4.0, property changes were handled with events. In 4.0, watching for property changes has become much easier. This is handled via the .watch(property, callback) method. The callback is called each time the property changes and allows you to work with the property's new value, old value, and name along with the watched object.

this is what a generic callback looks like:

```
var propertyChangeHandler = function(newValue, oldValue, property, object){  
  console.log("New Value: ",newValue," Old Value: ",oldValue,
  " Changed Property: ",property," Watched Object: ",object);
};
```

the benefit is that you are no longer restricted to listening for a subset of events bubbled up from within the API. instead, *all* properties can now be checked for changes.

Comment: Certainly, I understand your point, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I will look into this new 'watchable' change

Comment: @whyzar and OP my pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set up the event listener as follows. More information [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/watch-for-changes/index.html)

> // Listen to the click event on the map view.
>   view.on("click", function(event) {
>     console.log("click event: ", event.mapPoint);
>   });
>
> The sample also shows how to listen to events. It listens to the change event on the map's allLayers property. In this case, we only track when layers are added to the map. It also listens to the layerview-create event on the view to get notified when each layer in the map has a corresponding LayerView and is rendered in the view. Lastly, we listen to the click event on the view

Comment: the OP could have been more explicit, but its evident by his reference to MapView that he is not working with version 3.x of the JSAPI: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html

Comment: Yes, the sample code and reference page I provided is from version 4.x. I'm not sure what you are viewing.

Comment: because its 4.x, an event listener is irrelevant here. because he's interested in scale changes, a click listener is even more irrelevant.

Comment: i intended to include a "zoom" versus the "click", that was just the sample code I referenced to.

Comment: as i pointed out in my own answer, event listeners for checking things like zoom and scale have been deprecated in 4.x in favor of watchable properties.